# Iterate through list boolean print out what failed C#

Tags: c#, sql

I am doing an assertion to find some sql fields from what database to another.

```
bool ContainsBracketsWithString = AssertionValue.All(a =>
             CredentialTypeDescription.Any(b =>
                 a.Field1 == b.Field1
                 )
               );

Assert.False(ContainsBracketsWithString);
```

This works fine on telling me if it passes or fails, but when it fails I want to know which values didn't match.

Can somebody provide some code on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do both in one pass

```
string message = String.Empty;
bool ContainsBracketsWithString = AssertionValue.All(a =>
             CredentialTypeDescription.Any(b => {
                     var passed = a.Field1 == b.Field1;
                     if(!passed && String.IsNullOrEmpty(message)){
                        message = "Some message to identify which failed"; 
                     }
                     return passed;
                 })
               );

Assert.False(ContainsBracketsWithString, message);
```

Comment: well how will i know which failed? I want it to iterate through all the values and return the failed value. So some message would need to include the failed values. Is VAR passed iterating through the values?

Comment: You could use reflection to identity a and b. Given that you will be the one writing the fields then just name the fields in your message

Comment: works at finding the first field that fails, achieves the same as an built in assertion:

Comment: That is because the `Any` extension exits at the first match.

Comment: quick question how can i write the message only once? Should i remove fails list? Because this way it prints the message as many times as the .Any so if I have 10,000 results, it will print the same line 10,000 times

Comment: You could check `fails.Count`. I only used a list because i thought you wanted a message for each fail. you could just as easily used a string variable and set the string on fail.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the above ^ thanks, new to C#. Basically in the assertion I want to print the first failed record a.Field1. I can open a new question if you like